# What are the possible health consequences of using whitening strips?

Tags: dentistry, gums, white-strips-teeth

> Whitening strips are very thin, virtually invisible strips that are
>   coated with a peroxide-based whitening gel. The strips are applied
>   twice daily for 30 minutes for 14 days. Initial results are seen in a
>   few days and final results are sustained for about four months.
>   [{1}](http://www.webmd.com/oral-health/teeth-whitening)

However, I heard from someone that whitening strips can cause gum deterioration.

Are there studies that indicate teeth-whitening strips have negative consequences on teeth or general health?

Comment: I have also heard that they can break down enamel or otherwise make teeth weaker and cause more harm than good. I would like to know the answer to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a study which show that teeth whitening using Hydrogen Peroxide can cause oral mucosa irritation, burns or sensitive teeth. However, these were found to be mild in nature and resolved spontaneously without any intervention. Since teeth whitening strips are hydrogen peroxide based, I think the results can be safely extrapolated.

References:

1. [Teeth whitening with 6% hydrogen peroxide vs. 35% hydrogen peroxide, a comparative controlled study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25799793)